# JavaScript: *Can* set property of undefined with call / apply / bind?

Tags: javascript, function, properties, undefined, bind

I think I just discovered a new weird thing about JavaScript.

Does someone know how exactly this happens?

```js
let test;

function setProp() {
  this.prop = 42;
}
setProp.call(test);

// No error yet?
// So 42 should be saved inside test.prop?

// Though test=undefined?

console.log(test);
try {
  console.log(test.prop);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message);
}

// -> undefined
// -> Cannot read property 'prop' of undefined
// Ok, indeed

function getProp() {
  console.log(this.prop);
}
getProp.call(test);

// -> 42
// Wait, what?
```

I'm just curious :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In non-strict mode, passing `undefined` as the first argument to `.call()` implies that you want it to be the global object (like `window`).

Try your test with `"use strict";` at the top and see if that makes a difference.